# SQL работа с тремя таблицами

Tags: sql

Извините если вопрос глупый, но я не смог найти решение самостоятельно, а опыта еще мало.

есть 3 таблицы
 - flat
 - flat_contact
 - contact

в первой таблице есть строки ID и nomer
во второй таблице есть 3 строки id flat_id contact_id
в третьей таблице есть 2 строки ID и name

Надо сопоставить id квартиры с именем хозяина.
Догадываюсь что надо получить массивы первой и третьей таблицы и от этого играть, но не понимаю как.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант можно использовать JOIN, в таком духе:

```
SELECT f.nomer , c.name
FROM flat as f
INNER JOIN flat_contact as fc
    ON f.id = fc.flat_id
INNER JOIN contact as c
    ON fc.contact_id = c.id
WHERE c.name = 'SOME NAME'
```

Comment: Кстати это мысль. Сейчас буду пробовать!